# MPAndroidChart, update data from textView

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I am trying to get the chart to refresh every time the value in the textView changes. Following is the snippet from onCreate.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

```
final ArrayList<Entry> entriesa= new ArrayList<>();
final LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
final LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(entriesa,"AWAY");
final LineData data = new LineData(dataset);

entriesa.add(new Entry(0,0));
lineChart.setData(data);
lineChart.invalidate();


final TextView viewa1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sa1);
viewa1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
String s=viewa1.getText().toString();
int iv = Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));

    public void beforeTextChanged ( CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after ) {

    }
    public void afterTextChanged ( Editable s ) {

    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count ) {
    entriesa.set(0,new Entry(0,iv));
    data.notifyDataChanged();
    lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lineChart.invalidate();}
});
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but maybe the Entry into your final ArrayList is also final ? But I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding to the array list, declared LineData inside onTextChanged and appended to LineData with a new entry using addEntry.

Now, data is declared on each onTextChanged with previously held data using getData() and then latest entry is added using addEntry. This creates a continuous stream.. like real time data. I also used ILineDataSet because I have multiple data points on the same chart.

10 data points to the viewport and now I have a nice auto scrolling line chart in my app.

```
LineData data = lineChart.getData();
ILineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
data.addEntry(new Entry(set.getEntryCount(),iv),0);
data.notifyDataChanged();
lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10);
lineChart.moveViewToX(data.getEntryCount());
```